# how to display our data in json format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, next.js

am new in next JS , I want to display my index.js file data in dynamicid.js file in JSON format , can anyone tell me how can I display it.

> index.js

This is the index.js file where My output is displayed, but I want to display my output data in particular route in JSON Format.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

import { getDataFromSheets} from './libs/sheets'

export default function Home({data}) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Nextsheet </title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Welcome to Nextsheet </h1>
        <p>Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database</p>
        <ul>
          {data && data.length ? (
            data.map((item) => (
              <li key={item}>
                {item.title} - {item.description} 
              </li>
            ))
          ) : (
            <li>Error: do not forget to setup your env variables </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
// console.log(process.env.NAME);
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
 
  const sheet = await getDataFromSheets();
  return {
    props: {
      data: sheet.slice(0, sheet.length), // remove sheet header
    },
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  };
}
```

> dynamicid.js

This is my route file where I want to display my data in JSON Format.

```
export default  function handler(req, res) {


  res.status(200).json(name : "Ashish")
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `json` method on `res` accepts a javascript object. your current implementation is not a valid JS.
to fix it use the following:

```
  res.status(200).json({name : "Ashish"})
```